# problem in comparing two dates

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, calendarextender

i use two `CalendarExtender` to combine two dates: **start date** and **end date** and i use a `compare validator` to validate that the end date is greater than the start date.

the problem that the validator fires when the day in the end date is smaller than the day in the start date even though the whole end date is greater than the whole start date ..

how to fix this problem?

my aspx:

**1-start date:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_startDate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="insertgroup" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_startDate"
    ErrorMessage="!" ValidationGroup="insertgroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="txt_startDate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" CultureAMPMPlaceholder=""
    CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder=""
    CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder=""
    Enabled="True" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txt_startDate">
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txt_startDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
    TargetControlID="txt_startDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

**2-end date:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_endDate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="insertgroup" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txt_endDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_endDate"
    Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="txt_endDate_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" CultureAMPMPlaceholder=""
    CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder=""
    CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder=""
    Enabled="True" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txt_endDate">
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_endDate"
    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="!" ValidationGroup="insertgroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txt_startDate"
    ControlToValidate="txt_endDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="????? ??????? ??? ?? ???? ??? ?? ????? ???????"
    Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date" ValidationGroup="insertgroup"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

**EDIT:**
Example for two dates make problems:

```
//error message
    start date: 
    28/01/2014

    end date :
    25/07/2014
```

---

while

```
// no error message
    start date: 
    28/01/2014

    end date :
    01/07/2014
```

Comment: It works fine for me. I tried the example from this post http://weblogs.asp.net/sahannet/archive/2011/02/01/date-compare-validator-control-asp-net.aspx

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing strings. Therefore, it will be done alphabetically, rather than as a date data type.

Comment: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6997

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some more information as to why you're getting this behavior, and why Chad's code will help you.

Right now your application is running under a culture setting that says dates should be mm/dd/yyyy (your computer or the webserver is working like an American). If you look at the javascript that ASP.NET emits for the Validators, you'll see that when doing a comparison it first checks whether the datatype of the ControlToValidate is correct. It does this by parsing the entered value with a RegEx, and expects the month value to be first and then the day (because of the culture setting). When it sees your value of 25, it doesn't think this is a valid month, and hence says that your date is not valid. It then returns false, without even checking the second field's date value or trying to compare them.

In your second example, validation passes because first, it checks the datatype of the end date, which CAN be a valid mm/dd/yyyy date. Then it checks the datatype of the second date, which because of the 28, causes it to think it's not a valid date. The validator then returns true, because it assumes that a valid date is greater than a non-valid date.

Chad's code will set the culture of your page's thread to one that uses the dd/MM/yyyy format, and therefore your validators will use that when checking whether your dates are valid.

Here's [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) with more info about the culture settings and what they do.

Comment: "the webserver is working like an American" read working correctly :p

Comment: thanks , but i get the same error. i don't what is the problem?your explanation so great and logical for me , and i thought i solve the problem but still after Chad's code ,i face the same problem.

Comment: Finally i get it thanks alot .
i put `Culture="ar-EG"` in the page directive and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in the page load in the code behind

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo vCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").Clone(); 
vCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/mm/yyyy";    
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = vCulture;
```